# Find similar rows that have differences on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've an sql table like this:

```
ID    NR    Status
1     510     2
2     510     2
3     510     2
.     ...     .
17    987     2
33    987     3
35    987     2
```

I want to get table that; 
If **NR** column has same values and **Status** column has different values. 
So, I want to get table that contains 17, 33 and 35 rows.

I try this but it does not work:

```
select * from table1 as t1
inner join table1 t2 ON t1.NR=t2.NR and t1.Status != t2.Status
```

Comment: why you need `nr 35` it has same status

Comment: @TheGameiswar, row with same NR but other Status exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions:

```
select 
    *
from
    your_table
having
    count(distinct status) over (partition by nr) > 1;
```

window function v2:

```
select * from
(select 
    t.*,
    count(distinct status) over (partition by nr) cnt
from
    your_table t
) t where cnt > 1;
```

Using Joins:

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
inner join (
    select nr
    from your_table
    group by nr
    having count(distinct status) > 1
) t2 on t1.nr = t2.nr;
```

Using IN:

```
select *
from your_table t1
where nr in (
    select nr
    from your_table
    group by nr
    having count(distinct status) > 1
);
```

Using exists:

```
select *
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from your_table t2
    where t2.nr = t1.nr
    and t1.status <> t2.status
);
```

Comment: Why don't you add an EXISTS query too?

Comment: There you go.. @jarlh . . .

Comment: What if I want to get same NR's and same Status' values table? So the table that contains 1, 2 and 3 rows. @GurV

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    *
from
    table
where
    count(distinct status) over (partition by nr) > 1;
```